# Failed to launch Sagemath in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, sagemath

I have installed SageMath in Ubuntu 18.04. However I cannot launch sagemath from the applications (actually it is not even there) neither can I launch from command line.

```
(base) dimitris@dimitris-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get install sagemath
[sudo] password for dimitris: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sagemath is already the newest version (8.1-7ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libffi6:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386
  libllvm7:i386 libmpcdec6 libostree-1-1 libpciaccess0:i386 libplacebo4
  libsensors4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxxf86vm1:i386 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) dimitris@dimitris-Inspiron-5567:~$ sagemath
sagemath: command not found
```

When I type

```
apt list --installed
```

I see sagemath in the list of applications installed.

I used to use sagemath in 16.04 without problem. Is there any problem with 18.04? Am I missing something? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main Sage executable is named `sage`, it came from [`sagemath-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sage) package.
And this package was installed as dependency of [`sagemath` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sagemath).

So you need to give single command:

```
sage
```